# Column alias with Table alias

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My question is, what type of column alias it is?

```
SELECT serial_no = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number),Item 
  FROM (SELECT Number, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING('Anaemia|Anorexia|Cachexia', Number, 
                     CHARINDEX('|', 'Anaemia|Anorexia|Cachexia' + '|', Number) - Number)))
          FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
                  FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS APPLY sys.all_objects) AS x(Number)--n--(Number)
                 WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN('Anaemia|Anorexia|Cachexia'))
                   AND SUBSTRING('|' + 'Anaemia|Anorexia|Cachexia', Number, 1) = '|'
                ) AS y
```

In `from` clause the table alias is `x(Number)`. This `Number` is used as column in outer queries. So my question is what type of column/table alias `x(Number)` it is? First time I have seen this type of aliasing.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to post a simple example. The complicated one in the question is only confusing the matter. Consider the query with a subquery (derived table) where the columns have been provided new aliases:

```
SELECT 
    e.employee_id, 
    e.manager_id
FROM
    ( SELECT emp_id AS employee_id,             -- column alias
             mgr_id AS manager_id               -- column alias
      FROM employees
    ) 
      AS e ;                           -- table alias
```

The derived table has the alias `e` and the its columns have the aliases `employee_id` and `manager_id`.

You could rewrite it as:

```
SELECT 
    e.employee_id, 
    e.manager_id
FROM
    ( SELECT emp_id AS emp,       -- column alias
             mgr_id AS mgr        -- column alias
      FROM employees
    ) 
      AS e 
         ( employee_id,        -- column alias, overrides "emp"
           manager_id          -- column alias, overrides "mgr"
         ) ;
```

The end result is exactly the same. These aliases (`employee_id`, `manager_id`) - in either rewriting of the query - can be used in the level of the main query.

If you have aliases in both places, then the second ones overwrite the internal ones. So the `emp` and `mgr` above can only be used inside the `e` subquery and not outside.